# Is there a way to pass a variable after 5 seconds?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-mojave, swift5

I'm creating a desktop app with Swift and I need to pass a `stop` boolean after 5 seconds. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asyncAfter to create an async delay. After the 5.0 seconds you can do what you want.

```
var stop: Bool = false

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) { // runs after 5.0 seconds
    // pass your stop boolean here
}
```